# SSL 3 on a SOAP service

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, client

I need to develop against an appliance which uses SSL v3. Apparently .NET has dropped support for this because when I try to open a client generated from the WSDL I get the following error:

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   '10.10.12.10:8090'

sample code:

```
    public void SignOn()
    {
        using (var client = new AdminMgmtClient())
        {
            var login = new UserLoginAttributes { userName = "vem-user", password = "abcdefg" };
            var signOnResult = new Result();
            _sessionHandle = client.signOn(login, out signOnResult);
        }  
    }
```

I assume it has to do with the SSL v3 being unsafe, and we're working with the manufacturer of the appliance to get it to TLS, but for the mean time: how can I enable SSL v3 on the client?